# Pathfinding with 3D obstacles

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm

I recently looked into pathfinding as a side project and developed a simple application (C++) that finds the optimal path (A->B) around one/several random obstacles using A* on a quadtree.
As a next step I want to go 3D. So think for example of a drone that could either fly around a object, like a house, or go over it. What data representation and what pathfinding algorithm (for the shortest way) is suitable for such a task?

Another approach I thought of using my existing app: 
step 1: use quadtree + A* to calculate shortest way around
step 2: calculate the distance to (safely) fly over house and descend afterwards
step 3: Pick the better of the two. 
Problem: pathplanning for flyover has to be done separately.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/14rfsv/a_pathfinding_in_3d_space/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment list A* can be used well in 3D

Comment: Yes, I saw that reddit thread aswell. But I guess I can't use quadtrees in a 3D world?

Comment: You could use an octree instead, but if you really want to stick to quad trees then it would be a poorer solution as it would be a solving a slice or plane through the 3d world.